# Debate in the Python course about efficiency

Tags: python, performance

```
n = int(input())
L = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        L.append(i * j)
for i in range(n):
    l = L[:] + [i]
```

Is the efficiency of the code below is n^3 or n^2? does the third loop is n^3 due to the copy operator?

Answer (score 2):

```
n = int(input())
L = []
for i in range(n):  # --> O(n+1)                                #!
    for j in range(n): # --> O(n+1(n+1)) = O(n^2+2n+1)          #NESTED!
        L.append(i ** j) # --> O(n*n) k=depth of loops -> k*=n -> O(n^2)
for i in range(n): #---> O(n+1)                      #INDEPENDENT NEW LOOP
    l = L[:] + [i] #----> O(n)

### ----> Total = O(2n^2+5n+3) ==> O(n^2)
```